# Get the comma separated list from an array

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0

I have a function which has a return type of `IList<Product>`

```
class Product
{
  int Id,
  string ProductClass,
  string ProductName
}
```

I have to make a comma separated string of `ProductName`. I am trying below code but it is not giving me correct result

```
Array arrayofProduct = MyFunction().ToArray();
string productNames = string.Join(",", arrayofProduct);
```

I think it is because `arrayofProduct` has 3 columns and I have to pass only 1 (i.e. `ProductName`) to get the comma separated list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Linq to `Select` the `ProductName` into a collection and then use that to construct the desired comma separated string

```
var names = MyFunction().Select(p => p.ProductName);
string productNames = string.Join(",", names);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or apart from the above answer you can directly query your array of product and get the result.

```
string productNames = string.Join(",", arrayofProduct.Select(x => x.ProductName);
```